# Assigning Azure Blob Storage Content-Type with Terraform Dynamically

Tags: azure, terraform, azure-blob-storage, content-type

Is there a way to set the content-type for Azure Blob Storage using Terraform that dynamically infers the file extension ? Currently it just defaults to "application/octet-stream" which downloads the file instead of just serving it in browser. The issue is I am using a for_each to upload all files to blob storage using Terraform which is working perfectly but the content-type needs to correlate with the assets I am uploading which consists of json, html, pdf, png etc.

An example of my current code to loop through my assets folder and add it to my Azure Blob Storage container. Just not sure about the content-type.

```
resource "azurerm_storage_blob" "Example" {
for_each = fileset("${path.root}/assets/", "**/*")
name = each.key
storage_account_name = azurerm_storage_account.example.name
storage_container_name = azurerm_storage_container.example.name
type = "Block"
source = "${path.root}/assets/${each.key}"
content_md5 = filemd5("${path.root}/assets/${each.key}")
content-type = ?
}
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Please take a look here - https://engineering.statefarm.com/blog/terraform-s3-upload-with-mime/. Even though this blog is about S3 but the same concept would apply to Azure Blob Storage as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I tried to reproduce in my environment.

I have the files in below folder with different format.
[image]
I have tried creating a mime.json file to map the formats

mime.json:

```
{
    ".123": "application/vnd.lotus-1-2-3",
    ".3dml": "text/vnd.in3d.3dml",
    ".3g2": "video/3gpp2",
    ".3gp": "video/3gpp",
    ".a": "application/octet-stream",
    ".aac": "audio/x-aac",
    ".json":"application/json",
    ".txt":"text/plain",
    ".csv":"text/csv",
    ".png":"image/png",
   
  }
```

main.tf

```
locals {
  mime_types = jsondecode(file("${path.module}/mime.json"))
}
resource "azurerm_storage_blob" "uploadblolb" {
  for_each = fileset(path.module, "filetoupload/*")
 
  name                   = trim(each.key, "filetoupload/")
  storage_account_name   = azurerm_storage_account.example.name
  storage_container_name = azurerm_storage_container.example.name
  type                   = "Block"
  content_md5            = filemd5(each.key)
  source                 = each.key
  content-type =  lookup(local.mime_types, regex("\\.[^.]+$", each.value), null)
}
```

And then got files uploaded in expected content type .

[image]